# How can I update value of field from value of field another on the table?

Tags: mysql

I have table products

I have id, ...., photo, photo_list

```
id  photo            photo_list
1   chelsea.jpg      [{"id": "1", "name": "chelsea.jpg"}, {"id": "2", "name": "mu.jpg"}]
2   mu.jpg           NULL
3   city.jpg         NULL
4   arsenal.jpg      [{"id": "1", "name": "arsenal.jpg"}]
5   liverpool.jpg    NULL
```

Like that

I want to change it to be like this :

```
id  photo            photo_list
1   chelsea.jpg      [{"id": "1", "name": "chelsea.jpg"}, {"id": "2", "name": "mu.jpg"}]
2   mu.jpg           [{"id": "1", "name": "mu.jpg"}]
3   city.jpg         [{"id": "1", "name": "city.jpg"}]
4   arsenal.jpg      [{"id": "1", "name": "arsenal.jpg"}]
5   liverpool.jpg    [{"id": "1", "name": "liverpool.jpg"}]
```

So if photo_list field is null, then it will get from photo field

Is it possible to use mysql script to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use update and ( buil the proper string  ) for null values

```
  update products
  set photo_list = concat('[{"id": "1", "name": "', photo, '"}]')
  where photo_list is null
```